# LINQ What does 'select new' do?

Tags: c#, linq

I've built the following LINQ query

```
var activeMembers = from m in context.py3_membershipSet
                    join c in context.ContactSet on m.py3_Member.Id equals c.ContactId 
                    where m.statuscode.Value == 1
                    orderby m.py3_name
                    select m;
```

But I've since seen an example formatted as such:

```
var contacts =
(
    from c in xrm.ContactSet
    join a in xrm.AccountSet on c.ParentCustomerId.Id equals a.Id
    where a.Name == "Acme Pty Ltd"
    select new
    {
        Name = c.FullName,
        DOB = c.BirthDate,
        Gender = (c.FormattedValues.Contains("gendercode") ? c.FormattedValues["gendercode"] : "Ambiguous")
    }
);
```

(I realise this is a different set of data) What does the inclusion of the 'select new' actually do in this case?

What are the benefits of it over my example in the first code block?

I realise some might find this a tedious question, but I a want to learn LINQ and need to learn it fast. But I also don't want to run something -that I don't fully understand- on a clients live CRM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As previous answers have noted both methods return an anonymous type. To fully answer your question though: "What are the benefits of the second statement over the first?"

The first statement returns all of the fields of `m` as-is. If you have 7 "columns" then `activeMembers` will contain all of them and whatever data they contain.

In the second statement you're projecting the results into a custom anonymous object that has only 3 fields. Not only that but you can perform logic on the "source fields" before storing them in the anonymous object. This gives you much of the flexibility of storing them in a container class without you actually having to define that class in code.

You could also do `select new SomeClass { }` which would project your results into a predefined class container.

*The following pseudo-code may or may not be helpful in understanding the difference:*

```
var myQuery = from p in someContext.someTable
              group p by p.someField into g
              select new MyContainer {
                  Field1 = g.Sum(a => a.field1)
                  Field2 = g.Max(a => a.field2)
              };
```

`myQuery` in the above is now a collection of `MyContainer`. If I had omitted the class `MyContainer` then it would be a collection of an Anonymous Type containing the fields that I specified. Obviously, the difference here is that `MyContainer` has to be defined elsewhere in your code whereas the anonymous class is built/defined for you at compile time. In:

```
var myQuery = from p in someContext.someTable
              select p;
```

`myQuery` is an anonymous class containing all of the fields and their values in `someTable`.

Comment: So essentially, the 2nd query is limiting the result to a defined group with known names rather than an undefined set of x fields(as in the first) ?

Comment: Yes and no. The set of x fields in the first are still "known" (at least to the compiler). You could see this in the IDE by typing `activeMembers.FirstOrDefault().` and the available fields would pop up. The second option merely gives you more control over what goes into the anonymous type, what the fields are named, and allows you to perform calculations on the fields.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ returns a collection of anonymous objects, either way.  `select new` let's you define the layout of that object and which properties/property names are included in that anonymous object.

You can also use `select new ClassName { }` to return a list of instances of an entity class that you define.

Comment: Linq returns a collection, not an anonymous object, unless you're using one of the operators like Single or First or Count.  The Anonymous Type specifies the public members of each element in that collection.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Queryable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>)` method where ContactSet is the TSource and the of anonymous object return type is the TResult.  Your code could also be written as

```
...Select(r => new { 
                        Name = c.FullName, 
                        DOB = c.BirthDate, 
                        Gender = (c.FormattedValues.Contains("gendercode") ? c.FormattedValues["gendercode"] : "Ambiguous") 
                    })
```

where the select method is returning a collection of anonymous types.

Also, there is a bit more going on under the hood since it looks like you're querying the database.  Your implementation of IQueryable looks at the Select method that you've written, and translates the expression you've provided into valid SQL so that it can retrieve all the necessary information for the anonymous object that you're returning.  Notice that I said your implemenation of IQuerable translates the provided *expression* (not function) into sql.  The Select extension method only accepts expressions, not functions because it can't translate functions to sql.